# VBA 2010 copying range cells between 2 sheets on the same workbook avoid loop

Tags: excel, copy, range, cells, vba

These lines are intended to copy a range of one line cells from a sheet (source) to another (target) on the same workbook.

The following code raises `error 1004 - Application-defined or object-defined` :

```
currBook.Sheets(strNomOnglet).Range(Cells(firstrow, 2), Cells(firstrow, 8)).Copy _Destination:=currBook.Sheets(strOngletCibl).Range("B1:H1")

firstrow variable is a seeking sequence result.
```

This one is ok but too static (not relative referencing):

```
currBook.Sheets(strNomOnglet).Range("B26:H26").Copy _Destination:=currBook.Sheets(strOngletCibl).Range("B1:H1")
```

I'd like to avoid using a loop.

Any tips or explanation for that issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this one instead:

```
With currBook.Sheets(strNomOnglet)
    .Range(.Cells(firstrow, 2), .Cells(firstrow, 8)).Copy _
        Destination:=currBook.Sheets(strOngletCibl).Range("B1:H1")
End With
```

note that I've changed `Cells(firstrow, 2)` to `.Cells(firstrow, 2)` (to fully qualify your cells, i.e. specify to which sheet they are belongs)

Also if you want to copy *only values* (without formatting), it's better to use following code:

```
currBook.Sheets(strOngletCibl).Range("B1:H1").Value = _
    currBook.Sheets(strNomOnglet).Cells(firstrow, 2).Resize(, 7).Value
```

where `.Cells(firstrow, 2).Resize(, 7)` is shorter version of `.Range(.Cells(firstrow, 2), .Cells(firstrow, 8))`

Comment: Ok, thank you simoco
But, there's another detail not corrected : the destination sheet is not the same...

Comment: The problem in my code seems that it needs specifically a selection and switching between the source and destination.

Comment: So sorry : none of them functions. 

Only the static statement when I try back to it :-/

Comment: 1) what error have you got? 2) what value in your `firstrow` when you run the macro? 3) have you changed something in my code?

Comment: No error just no effect. __firstrow__ is ok by debugging no major change

Comment: check your `firstrow` again. It may oppears that you copy emtpy row or something else. Code should work

Comment: Ideally, I target the use of Cells(numrow,numcol) to move through ranges of cells because the datas are spread in weird order inside each block...

Comment: Ok. I try again looking at the variable content.

Comment: It's OK now. I've made mistake... :-/ :-)